# How to draw a point moving on a circle with Desmos graphing calculator?

Tags: graphing-functions, desmos

This is a soft question.

It's not difficult , say, to draw a point moving on the $y=x^2$ parabola with Desmos.

One can first declare that $b= a^2 $ , then define point $P$ as $P=(a,b) $ , and finally let vary $a$.

But this " method" does not work with the equation of a circle , first setting, say, $a^2+b^2=1$.

Any solution? Or hint?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I think a working answer would be $(sin(a),cos(a))$, where $a$ is a variable between $0$ and $2\pi$ radians, or $0$ and $360$ for degrees. You could also use this to make a circle using a parametric, with $(sin(t),cos(t))$, $t$ being a variable that's built-in for parametrics, just make sure to set the limits for $t$ as what you would've put earlier for $a$.